# Laravel exit code when condition in a loop is not met

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I am trying to loop through an array and meet a condition before submitting to database. The else block must not run if one item in the loop passes the condition, all must pass before it submits but the issue I'm having is that if one item passes, it submits and still returns the exception for the others. Here is my function

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $item_count; $i++) {
    switch ($fields['comment'][$i]) {
        case null:
            if($fields['qty_issued'][$i] != $fields['qty_received'][$i]) {
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors(['Failed!', 'Please provide reason!']);
            } else {
                # Receive voucher Items
                $received_items = ReceivedItems::create([
                    'item_id' => $fields['item_id'][$i],
                    'qty' => $fields['qty_received'][$i],
                    'voucher_code' => $fields['voucher_code'],
                    'comment' => $fields['comment'][$i],
                ]);
            }
            break;

        default:
            #code.... 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am looping through an array to see _item_issued_  matches with _item_received_, if not then there must be a comment why they dont match before submitting the code to database, but when I check and one item in the array passes the test, it submits it to database and returns the rest as error. But I dont want it that way, I want that even if one passes, all must pass the condition before submitting

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in a controller method, with input coming from the user? Why are you not using validation?

Comment: Yes the code is from a controller from a user input, I havnt thought of a validation rule that can meet the problem I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want all of your data to be inserted into your database or none.
If this is the case, I suggest using database transactions.
The documentation for this can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions

The code for this should look like

```
DB::beginTransaction(); //Begin transaction we can rollback or commit later
for($i = 0; $i < $item_count; $i++){
        switch ($fields['comment'][$i]) {
            case null:
            if($fields['qty_issued'][$i] != $fields['qty_received'][$i]){
                DB::rollBack(); //We don't want to save the changes we made before
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Failed!', 'Please provide reason why you\' receiving a lesser quantity for  in the comment box!']);
            }else{
            #Receive voucher Items
            $received_items = ReceivedItems::create([
            'item_id' => $fields['item_id'][$i],
            'qty' => $fields['qty_received'][$i],
            'voucher_code' => $fields['voucher_code'],
            'comment' => $fields['comment'][$i],
             ]);
           }
         break;

        default:
        #code.... 
        break;
        }

    }
DB::commit(); //Everything succeeded and we can commit our changes to the database
```